# How to authorize baseimage user to use mkdir

Tags: linux, docker, dockerfile

I'm writting a dockerfile which looks like the following

```
FROM <IMAGENAME>:<TAG> AS base
ENV MY_VAR=/opt/test
RUN mkdir -p $MY_VAR ....
```

Since my base image has its own user (for the sake of argument lets call the user **"baseImageUser"**) who has no privileges to execute mkdir I get the following error

```
mkdir: cannot create directory '/opt/test' : Permission denied
```

I know I can add

```
USER root
```

and then change the ownership, but this looks a bit hacky to me, is there another way to give **"baseImageUser"** privileges to create the folder?

Comment: As /opt/test is not present in home dir . So have two options give this user privileges or create dir by root user.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you, use the home directory of the `baseImageUser`. and check the `WORKDIR` option as well, so that image uses it as the current directory and then perform operations in that directory.

```
FROM <IMAGENAME>:<TAG> AS base
WORKDIR /home/base
ENV MY_VAR=abc
RUN mkdir $MY_VAR 
....
```

If you want to run operations in `/` or `/opt` or `/usr` directory, then either mention as `USER root` and then assign permissions to your user because by default these directories are owned by `root` user in linux.